# How to delete all tables in Oracle XE 11.2 using Application Express?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I installed Oracle Express Edition 11.2, and have created an outline.
Using SQL Developer, SQL to practice, the problem is that every time you create a workspace, sample tables are created.

How I can delete those tables that are automatically created?

[image]

The tables are in the red box are those that are automatically created each time you create a workspace.

Comment: What "sample tables" are you talking about?  I can't recall APEX ever creating a new table just because a new workspace was created.  It would obviously create new tables if you installed a sample application in that workspace.  Are we talking about the data dictionary tables that always exist?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
If the tables are called Apex ...
Each time you create a workspace, these sample tables are created.
I want to create an empty workspace.

Comment: You are saying that when you create an APEX workspace, a table named `apex` is being created?  That seems highly unlikely.  Are you talking about the data dictionary tables `APEX_APPLICATIONS`, `APEX_PLSQL_JOBS`, etc?

Comment: Look at the picture below , these are the tables that tell you.

Comment: You'll want to edit your question when you have additional information to add rather than adding answers (unless you are intending to answer your own question).  You're posting a screenshot of an Oracle schema, not an APEX workspace.  An APEX workspace uses a schema but it's generally not a 1:1 relationship.  Are you creating a new schema in Oracle and then creating a new workspace in APEX that uses that new schema?  Or are you creating a new workspace that uses an existing schema? You'll need the `APEX$` tables, though, APEX uses them.  Unless you're trying to disable functionality...

Comment: I want to create an empty outline, without tables , to erase the boards of the red box one by one.

But you can how do I disable the functionality that you say?

Comment: The `APEX$` tables are required for APEX to function correctly.  Why do you want to remove them?  And can you answer the workspace vs schema questions I asked?

Comment: I want them removed because I want to add more tables , and so do not confuse me.

Regarding the questions , I realize the creation of a new scheme.

Answer (score 3):

The tables you listed in your screenshot are created automatically by Application Express when the workspace is created.

Some of them can be avoided by setting **Create demonstration objects in new workspaces** and **Create Websheet objects in new workspaces** to **No** (under Manage Instance -> Feature Configuration).

They are generally safe to drop - but note that the demo application will no longer work, and since the `APEX$..` tables are used by Websheets, **you won't be able to create Websheet applications in that workspace**.

This is the script I used on my last project where we didn't need any of this stuff (adapt to your list as required):

```
DROP SEQUENCE DEPT_SEQ;
DROP SEQUENCE EMP_SEQ;
DROP TABLE DEPT PURGE;
DROP TABLE EMP PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_ACL PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_FILES PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_HISTORY PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_LINKS PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_NOTES PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_ROWS PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_TAGS PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTIONS PURGE;
DROP TABLE APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTION_HISTORY PURGE;
```

**Use of this script is at your risk :)**